# Is it possible to manually change the colors of a barplot once that I used "scale_fill_discrete()" function?

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

I am trying to manually change the colors of a barplot based on a grouping variable. In order to properly order my values, I have to use the `scale_fill_discrete()` function, so that I cannot apply a `scale_fill_manual()` function (if more information is needed please leave a comment). My question is: do you know if it is possible to set a color this way?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: You should be able to order your values in any way you want using factors, and then apply a `scale_fill_manual()`. Please provide code so that we can reproduce your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `scale_fill_manual()` wouldn't be a problem. Because, it will override the previous colour scale you've used. I used an existing dataset to suit your problem.

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, fill = drv)) +
geom_bar()
```

This would create a plot like this. [image: first plot without customization]

If you want to customize, you can do this

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, fill = drv)) +
geom_bar() + 
scale_fill_manual(values=c("red", "black", "green"))
```

The above code will output this. [image: w/customizing]

If you want further control over your palettes, you can do this.

```
myColors <- c("4"="red", "f"="yellow", "r"="blue")
#myColors is a named vector
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, fill = drv)) +
geom_bar() + scale_fill_manual(values=myColors)
```

This will give you this:
[image: fully-controlled]

Comment: Thank you, but I should keep my `scale_fill_discrete`. Using `scale_fill_manual` would substitute my current options